# Spring AOP DeclareParents not working as expected

Tags: spring-aop

Can someone explain if I have a correct understanding of **DeclareParents** Spring annotation:

As per my understanding the below piece of code shall tells that all classes that implement interface Performance should also implement interface Rock as of now.

```
@DeclareParents(value = "com.example.demo.Performance.*+", defaultImpl = RockImpl.class)
    public static Rock rock;
```

Here's simple example of Rock interface

```
public interface Rock {

    void acDC();

}
```

However, when I try invoking method acDC on my class SongService which implements Performance - it doesn't work.

Appreciate your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

The target type expression is incorrect.

A target type expression : `com.example.demo.Performance.*+` would mean all implementors of interfaces within package `com.example.demo.Performance`

For all implementors of `Performance` interface to also implement `Rock` interface the expression should be as follows

```
 @DeclareParents(value="com.example.demo.Performance+", defaultImpl=RockImpl.class)
 public static Rock rock;
```

Reference : [Introductions](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-introductions)

[AspectJ Type Patterns](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/quick-typePatterns.html) : Go through the subtype pattern

[Fixing subtypes in introduction](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/porting.html#1.0a1-subtypes-to-plus)